# How to get the value of "name" field from the json using jsonpath expression

Tags: java, json, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I want to get the value against "name" field from the below json. I tried using the tools http://jsonpathfinder.com/ and http://jsonpath.com/?
I am using http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/ to verify if the expression path is correct, but it always returns me as an incorrect expression.

```
{
  "data" : {
    "PensionRetriever(Customer=ABC, typeInfo=valid)" : {
      "name" : "lifeInsurance",
      "created_at" : 1552297775384,
      "attributes" : [ {
        "id" : "4044da39-c23b-4588-b6c4-975ce02e7cb2",
        "name" : "lifeInsurance",
        "created_at" : 1552297775384
   }]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried with `$.data["PensionRetriever(Customer=ABC, typeInfo=valid)"].name` , but this seems incorrect. Can you please tell me now to get the value of "name" , i.e., lifeInsurance

Comment: What do you mean with `incorrect` when you call `$.data["PensionRetriever(Customer=ABC, typeInfo=valid)"].name`? And what is returned when you call `console.log($.data)`?

Comment: It's giving me "Found empty property at index 55"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quoted rather than double quoted names in the JSONPath expression, i.e.

```
$.data['PensionRetriever(Customer=ABC, typeInfo=valid)'].name
```

Using the online evaluators on http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/, the usually reliable Jayway fails, apparently unable to digest the name `'PensionRetriever(Customer=ABC, typeInfo=valid)'`. That's a Jayway bug. But Goessner succeeds, returning the expected

```
[    "lifeInsurance" ]
```

Answer (score -1):

var path = $.JSONPath({data: json, keepHistory: false});
var test=path.query('$.data.PensionRetriever(Customer=ABC,typeInfo=valid).name');

Comment: This will not work cause when javascript sees a parenthesis it will try to evaluate the expression, not interpret it as a property of the object.

Comment: can use by query

Comment: @song bo, can you please elaborate.